# Can I use hidden gutter brackets on the ends of rafters with no fascia?

Tags: roofing, gutters

I'd like to install some gutters on my detached garage. Most of the instructions online assume that either:

- There's a fascia board attached to the ends of the roof rafters; in that case you attach the gutter hangers to the fascia board
- There's no roof rafters where you could attach a fascia board; in that case you use strap hangers.

I'm in kind of an intermediate place, and can't find anything about it in my research. My roof has rafters with no fascia board:

[image: roof rafters with no fascia board]

The rafters are 2ft apart, as indicated on the image - which is convenient because you're apparently supposed to place gutter hangers 2ft apart.

It seems like I should be able to install the gutters without placing a fascia board on top of the rafters; will that work? What are the downsides of skipping that step, if any?

Comment: Not a complete answer: one big downside to this setup as picture is that if you get any rain, those boards are going to rot.

Comment: @KMJ what do you mean by that? Would the rotting start if I installed gutters, or are you saying that the rafters are already going to rot?

Comment: In my experience unpainted board ends like this rot sooner rather than later. However it is very wet here!

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it seems you could use a hidden screw bracket like the one pictured below and anchor it into the end grain of the rafter tails. Perhaps the spike style installation would work too, but since those are larger in diameter, I wonder if they might run greater risk of splitting the rafter tails. (photo: [www.guttersupply.com](http://www.guttersupply.com))

[image: hidden bracket for K-style gutter]

Downsides that come to mind:

- should you decide later that you want to add soffit panels under the eave, you'll have more work to install the fascia board at that time.
- if it's necessary to lean a ladder against this side of the roof, I know from experience that a gutter *with a fasica board* will bear the load pretty well. I don't know how well a fascia-free gutter installation will fare.
- the gutter experiences some torsion force when it's loaded with wet leaves, sand from shingles, or ice. A fascia board helps support the gutter, preventing those loads from making the gutter twist by providing backing especially at the lower corner of the gutter. Without that support your gutters might be prone to getting deformed -- but I really don't know how large this risk may be.

Comment: OP could put boards between the rafter tails, to which the gutters could be fastened, avoiding the potential to split the rafters.  There's no easy way to fasten them butted, but you could nail alternating boards at top and bottom so that they can swivel a little bit, then rotate them to vertical and either pocket-screw or toe-nail them in place.  Would be a lot more work than just adding a fascia board, but I think doable.  Either that, or trim an inch off the tails and run a continuous board.

Comment: That'd be like post facto adding a fascia :) See also https://amigogutters.com/how-to-install-gutters-things-you-need-to-know-about-gutter-installation/